# Change task port for angular task in VS Code

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I am new VS Code and want to change the port which is used for the task which starts my Angular project. I am aware of both the `ng server --port=8080` and `npm start -- --port=8080` commands. However I could not find out how to pass the port into the following tasks.json.

1. I tried appending the argument to the script value
2. I tried adding a port key value in options -> env

I am sorry for asking this trivial question but I can't believe the npm task type does not allow the change of the port value.

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
      {
        "type": "npm",
        "script": "start",
        "isBackground": true,
        "presentation": {
          "focus": true,
          "panel": "dedicated"
        },
        "group": {
          "kind": "build",
          "isDefault": true
        },
        "problemMatcher": {
          "owner": "typescript",
          "source": "ts",
          "applyTo": "closedDocuments",
          "fileLocation": [
            "relative",
            "${cwd}"
          ],
          "pattern": "$tsc",
          "background": {
            "activeOnStart": true,
            "beginsPattern": {
              "regexp": "(.*?)"
            },
            "endsPattern": {
              "regexp": "Compiled |Failed to compile."
            }
          }
        }
      },
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit angular.json and add the following after serve.

```
"serve" :{
    // add below
       "options": {
        
        "port": 8080
      },
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but what I want to achieve is to have this port configuration set in the tasks.json file so I can just configure multiple different configs with different ports which I can then select in the dropdown next to the "Run And Debug" field in VSCode